# Spritekit - lower performance for A7 devices vs A6 devices?

Tags: xcode, performance, swift, build, game-engine

Hopefully this isnt a dumb question.  I've noticed my spritekit game runs at a rock solid 60 fps on my iphone 5..  but on iphone 5s, and iphone retina mini, I see my fps drop down to 52 - 55 fps.  I figured the newer devices would be faster, but the only thing I could think of is that these devices use a 64 bit processor, while my iphone 5 doesn't.  Could I have any kind of build setting issues?  It's odd newer devices would have worse performance.

I'm using standard architectures under build settings.  Do I need to do anything else?

[image]

Comment: try to make build in release mode

Comment: I tried this and I'm not sure i notice a difference. I need to experiment a little more. Thanks for your input

Comment: ok i think you were right, i'm upvoting your comment